# IIS Rewrite instead of redirect from directory

Tags: redirect, iis, directory, urlrewriter

How can I achieve this in IIS:

When I'll write in the browser: www.mydomain.com/mydirectory to go and point to subdomain.domain.com but the url to be like I've written it in my browser (eg.www.mydomain.com/mydirectory )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't rewrite a url to a different domain. You'd either have to do a redirect, or you can use an iframe to contain subdomain.domain.com inside of the page you have at www.mydomain.com/mydirectory.

If you want to rewrite subdomain.domain.com to something like domain.com/subdomain, this would be possible since it is the same domain name, here's the rule in web.config:

```
<rule name="RedirectSubdomain">
<match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*).domain.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{C:1}/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: iframe is out of the question as we would get penalty from Google-analitycs

I heard from a friend that on Linux I can rewrite the subdomain.domain.com to something like domain.com/subdomain witch is exactly what we want thing is I do not know how to rewrite url's ether on IIS or on apache :(

Comment: Ok that's not what you asked in your original question. I updated the answer with the rule if you want to go from subdomain.domain.com to domain.com/subdomain.